# Load various images at same time from the internet objective-c

Tags: objective-c, ios, load, uiimage

I'm trying to load 5 images at the same time,for them put it on the view and change the image every 5 sec(change between the current 5)
I create the current a class wich is called when the viewdidload and starts the timer,the method to load all images is this:

```
-(NSMutableArray *)getAllPhotos
{
    NSMutableArray * photosArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    NSString * pic0 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://74.53.32.202/~ltashiro/public/Servidor/Images/0.png"];
    NSString * pic1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://74.53.32.202/~ltashiro/public/Servidor/Images/1.png"];
    NSString * pic2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://74.53.32.202/~ltashiro/public/Servidor/Images/2.png"];
    NSString * pic3 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://74.53.32.202/~ltashiro/public/Servidor/Images/3.png"];

    NSURL *image0 = [NSURL URLWithString:pic0];
    NSURL * image1 = [NSURL URLWithString:pic1];
    NSURL * image2 = [NSURL URLWithString:pic2];
    NSURL * image3 = [NSURL URLWithString:pic3];

    NSMutableArray * arrayURL = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [arrayURL addObject:image0];
    [arrayURL addObject:image1];
    [arrayURL addObject:image2];
    [arrayURL addObject:image3];

    for (int i = 0; i<4; i++)
    {
        NSData * imageData = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[arrayURL objectAtIndex:i]];
        Photo * aPhoto = [[Photo alloc]init];
        aPhoto.photoID = (i+1);
        aPhoto.photo = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:imageData];

        [photosArray addObject:aPhoto];
        [aPhoto release];
        [imageData release];
    }

    return photosArray;
}
```

But sometimes the appcrashs on launch,theres any other solution abordation to it?

Comment: Why don't you load the asynchronously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was searching for the problem posted here. I found a solution here:
http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/loading-images-asynchronously-on-iphone-using-nsinvocationoperation

Didn't test it yet though.